# ReactJS: Validation not working with Yup using Formik multistep form

Tags: reactjs, formik, yup

I have a multi steps form in which i have used a `Formik` and `Yup` libraries.

But the validation that i am using of yup library is not working at all. In React debugger tool i am getting it's value as empty. So, whatever i write in the input field it validates with "Required" message as it's value is empty.

```
import { Formik, Form, Field, ErrorMessage } from 'formik';
import * as Yup from 'yup';

let accountInfoSchema = Yup.object().shape({
  name: Yup.string()
  .max(20, 'Too Long!')
  .required('Name is Required'),
});

class AccountInfo extends Component {
 handleChange = event => {
    this.setState({    
      userAccountData: Object.assign(
        {}, 
        this.state.userAccountData,
        { [event.target.name]: event.target.value }
      ),
    })
  }

 AccountInfoView = () => {
    return (
      <section className="form">
      <React.Fragment>
        <Formik
          initialValues={{name:'' }}
          validationSchema={accountInfoSchema}
          render={() => {
          return(
        <Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        {this.Step1()}
        {this.Step2()}
        {this.Step3()}
        <li className="stb_btn half">
          <div className="custom_group">
            {this.previousButton()}
          </div>
        </li>
        <li className="stb_btn half">
          <div className="custom_group">
            {this.nextButton()}
          </div>
        </li>
        </Form>
        );
      }}
      />
      </React.Fragment>
      </div>
    </section>
    )
  }

Step1 = () => {
return(
<li>
   <div className="custom_group">
   <Field type="text" name="name" className="trans text_input" placeholder="Enter your name" value={this.state.userAccountData['name']} onChange={this.handleChange} />
   <label className="label_two">Name</label>
   <ErrorMessage name="name" />
   </div>
 </li>
)
}

render() {    

    return (
      <div>{this.AccountInfoView()}</div>
    )
  }


}
```

please review the react console response for the value as empty.

[image]

Comment: I have already deleted my last question after knowing that these both are almost same. As my other two single paged forms are already working but this multi step is not working so that i asked this question... and i am already following this [tutorial](https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/docs/guides/validation)
. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason why it isn't validating is because you are passing to the `Field` `this.state.userAccountData['name']` and `onChange={this.handleChange}`.

Formik already have a state to store all of the data from your form, you don't need to keep it in the components state.

When you add `onChange={this.handleChange}` to the field, you change the component's state, but don't change the `Formik`'s state, this is why the validation isn't triggering.

I'm not sure why you are keeping the `name` in the state, but if you don't have any reason why these are unecessary.

```
 // formik already handle the state for you inside `values`
 handleChange = event => {
    this.setState({    
      userAccountData: Object.assign(
        {}, 
        this.state.userAccountData,
        { [event.target.name]: event.target.value }
      ),
    })
  }

// Formik already handles the value and the onChange of the input
<Field type="text" name="name" className="trans text_input" placeholder="Enter your name" value={this.state.userAccountData['name']} onChange={this.handleChange} />
```

The only thing you need is to set the field's `name` prop, so it matches the validation.

```
// this is enough
<Field type="text" name="name" className="trans text_input" placeholder="Enter your name" />
```

Comment: It is totally out of my mind that there is no need to pass a `value`; as i was creating a multistep form so my thinking was on that side that i need to pass a value so that i can get a value of multiple forms. Thank you so much...!!!

Comment: @Taalavya, the reason why you use formik is that it handles all the form state for you. You only need to handle state if you want to do some custom thing. You are welcome!